# How to synchronize 2 requests (samplers) in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have test in jmeter that call get oauth token (Token request) and than call rest web service. Problem is that it call Token request to early and when It call web service, it fails becouse token is no longer valid. Can someone help me to fix it in the way, that Token request will be executed few seconds before web service call?

My test config in jmeter

[image: My test]

Throughput Controller

[image]

Constant Throughput Timer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Normally you shouldn't do anything because each JMeter thread (virtual user) executes Samplers upside down and looking into your test plan I can see that the token request is before the authenticated request so it shouldn't be a problem (unless token life time is below 1 minute)

Whatever.

If you want to introduce a delay between 2 requests there are following options:

1. Add Flow Control Action Sampler before the 2nd request

   [image]
2. Add a relevant [JMeter Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timer) (i.e. [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer)) as a child of the 2nd request

   [image]